# How do I update this code and not get Run Time Error 3075?

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba, runtime

I've created a form where an employee can search for a customer by name or ID.  I am trying to add the ability to also select checkboxes with "Customer Types/Opportunity Types" to further filter the search results.  I get run time error 3075  Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

'Code to show results based on keyword entered and checkbox selected

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strText As String
    Dim NewBuild As String
    Dim Winback As String
    Dim Renewal As String

    If IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Or Me.txtSearch = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Name or ID to search!", vbOKOnly, "Keyword Needed"
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus

    Else

    If Me.chkNewBuild = True Then
        NewBuild = "New Build"
    End If

    If Me.chkWinback = True Then
        Winback = "Winback"
    End If

    If Me.chkRenewal = True Then
        Renewal = "Renewal"
    End If

    strText = txtSearch.Value
    strSearch = "SELECT * FROM qryPropertiesALL " _
    & "WHERE ((([OpportunityType] = " _
    & NewBuild & ")or ([OpportunityType] = " _
    & Winback & ") or ([OpportunityType] = " _
    & Renewal & ") AND (PropertyName like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Property_ID like ""*" & strText & "*"")))"
    Me.RecordSource = strSearch


    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

'Code to show results based on keyword entered and checkbox selected

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strText As String
    Dim NewBuild As String
    Dim Winback As String
    Dim Renewal As String

    If IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Or Me.txtSearch = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Name or ID to search!", vbOKOnly, "Keyword Needed"
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus

    Else

    If Me.chkNewBuild = True Then
        NewBuild = "New Build"
    End If

    If Me.chkWinback = True Then
        Winback = "Winback"
    End If

    If Me.chkRenewal = True Then
        Renewal = "Renewal"
    End If

    strText = txtSearch.Value
    strSearch = "SELECT * FROM qryPropertiesALL " _
    & "WHERE OpportunityType = '" _
    & NewBuild & "' or OpportunityType = '" _
    & Winback & "' or OpportunityType = '" _
    & Renewal & "' AND PropertyName like '" & strText & "' or Property_ID like '" & strText & "'"

    Me.RecordSource = strSearch

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On a side note, I recommend refraining from all the extra parenthesis and brackets if possible.  The brackets are only necessary if there is a space in the field name.  It makes troubleshooting your code much easier in situations like this.

Comment: Keep in mind how and/or relationships work.  If there is an OR in your WHERE clause, only one of the criterion has to be met for the statement to be true.  In your program, having multiple checkbooks for the same query might not work out as you plan.  Could you try an option group instead that only permits of of the three search criterion?

Comment: Go into design view for your form.  Under the DESIGN tab , select the Option Group under the Controls section.  A wizard will pop up that will help you fill out the necessary fields.  This allows the user to only select one value, not multiple.  You could then revise your SQL query to include the value returned from the option group in your WHERE clause.